# What's the equivalent of cut/qcut for pandas date fields?

Tags: python, pandas

**Update:  starting with version 0.20.0, pandas cut/qcut DOES handle date fields.  See [What's New](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew.html#whatsnew-0200-enhancements-other) for more.**

> pd.cut and pd.qcut now support datetime64 and timedelta64 dtypes (GH14714, GH14798)

**Original question:**  Pandas cut and qcut functions are great for 'bucketing' continuous data for use in pivot tables and so forth, but I can't see an easy way to get datetime axes in the mix. Frustrating since pandas is so great at all the time-related stuff!

Here's a simple example:

```
def randomDates(size, start=134e7, end=137e7):
    return np.array(np.random.randint(start, end, size), dtype='datetime64[s]')

df = pd.DataFrame({'ship' : randomDates(10), 'recd' : randomDates(10), 
                   'qty' : np.random.randint(0,10,10), 'price' : 100*np.random.random(10)})
df

     price      qty recd                ship
0    14.723510   3  2012-11-30 19:32:27 2013-03-08 23:10:12
1    53.535143   2  2012-07-25 14:26:45 2012-10-01 11:06:39
2    85.278743   7  2012-12-07 22:24:20 2013-02-26 10:23:20
3    35.940935   8  2013-04-18 13:49:43 2013-03-29 21:19:26
4    54.218896   8  2013-01-03 09:00:15 2012-08-08 12:50:41
5    61.404931   9  2013-02-10 19:36:54 2013-02-23 13:14:42
6    28.917693   1  2012-12-13 02:56:40 2012-09-08 21:14:45
7    88.440408   8  2013-04-04 22:54:55 2012-07-31 18:11:35
8    77.329931   7  2012-11-23 00:49:26 2012-12-09 19:27:40
9    46.540859   5  2013-03-13 11:37:59 2013-03-17 20:09:09
```

To bin by groups of price or quantity, I can use cut/qcut to bucket them:

```
df.groupby([pd.cut(df['qty'], bins=[0,1,5,10]), pd.qcut(df['price'],q=3)]).count()

                       price  qty recd ship
qty     price               
(0, 1]  [14.724, 46.541]   1   1   1   1
(1, 5]  [14.724, 46.541]   2   2   2   2
        (46.541, 61.405]   1   1   1   1
(5, 10] [14.724, 46.541]   1   1   1   1
        (46.541, 61.405]   2   2   2   2
         (61.405, 88.44]   3   3   3   3
```

But I can't see any easy way of doing the same thing with my 'recd' or 'ship' date fields. For example, generate a similar table of counts broken down by (say) monthly buckets of recd and ship.  It seems like resample() has all of the machinery to bucket into periods, but I can't figure out how to apply it here.   The buckets (or levels) in the 'date cut' would be equivalent to a pandas.PeriodIndex, and then I want to label each value of df['recd'] with the period it falls into?

So the kind of output I'm looking for would be something like:

```
ship    recv     count
2011-01 2011-01  1
        2011-02  3
        ...      ...
2011-02 2011-01  2
        2011-02  6
...     ...      ...
```

More generally, I'd like to be able to mix and match continuous or categorical variables in the output.  Imagine df also contains a 'status' column with red/yellow/green values, then maybe I want to summarize counts by status, price bucket, ship and recd buckets, so:

```
ship    recv     price   status count
2011-01 2011-01  [0-10)   green     1
                            red     4
                 [10-20) yellow     2
                  ...      ...    ...
        2011-02  [0-10)  yellow     3
        ...      ...       ...    ...
```

As a bonus question, what's the simplest way to modify the groupby() result above to just contain a single output column called 'count'?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a solution using pandas.PeriodIndex (caveat: PeriodIndex doesn't
seem to support time rules with a multiple > 1, such as '4M').  I think
the answer to your bonus question is `.size()`.

```
In [49]: df.groupby([pd.PeriodIndex(df.recd, freq='Q'),
   ....:             pd.PeriodIndex(df.ship, freq='Q'),
   ....:             pd.cut(df['qty'], bins=[0,5,10]),
   ....:             pd.qcut(df['price'],q=2),
   ....:            ]).size()
Out[49]: 
                qty      price 
2012Q2  2013Q1  (0, 5]   [2, 5]    1
2012Q3  2013Q1  (5, 10]  [2, 5]    1
2012Q4  2012Q3  (5, 10]  [2, 5]    1
        2013Q1  (0, 5]   [2, 5]    1
                (5, 10]  [2, 5]    1
2013Q1  2012Q3  (0, 5]   (5, 8]    1
        2013Q1  (5, 10]  (5, 8]    2
2013Q2  2012Q4  (0, 5]   (5, 8]    1
        2013Q2  (0, 5]   [2, 5]    1
```

Answer (score 4):

Just need to set the index of the field you'd like to resample by, here's some examples

```
In [36]: df.set_index('recd').resample('1M',how='sum')
Out[36]: 
                 price  qty
recd                       
2012-07-31   64.151194    9
2012-08-31   93.476665    7
2012-09-30   94.193027    7
2012-10-31         NaN  NaN
2012-11-30         NaN  NaN
2012-12-31   12.353405    6
2013-01-31         NaN  NaN
2013-02-28  129.586697    7
2013-03-31         NaN  NaN
2013-04-30         NaN  NaN
2013-05-31  211.979583   13

In [37]: df.set_index('recd').resample('1M',how='count')
Out[37]: 
2012-07-31  price    1
            qty      1
            ship     1
2012-08-31  price    1
            qty      1
            ship     1
2012-09-30  price    2
            qty      2
            ship     2
2012-10-31  price    0
            qty      0
            ship     0
2012-11-30  price    0
            qty      0
            ship     0
2012-12-31  price    1
            qty      1
            ship     1
2013-01-31  price    0
            qty      0
            ship     0
2013-02-28  price    2
            qty      2
            ship     2
2013-03-31  price    0
            qty      0
            ship     0
2013-04-30  price    0
            qty      0
            ship     0
2013-05-31  price    3
            qty      3
            ship     3
dtype: int64
```

Comment: This doesn't seem like a general solution, e.g. if I want to group on two different dates, or a date and a non-date (via cut or category variable).  I'll update the question with the structure of output I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I came up with an idea that relies on the underlying storage format of datetime64[ns].  If you define dcut() like this

```
def dcut(dts, freq='d', right=True):
    hi = pd.Period(dts.max(), freq=freq) + 1   # get first period past end of data
    periods = pd.PeriodIndex(start=dts.min(), end=hi, freq=freq)
    # get a list of integer bin boundaries representing ns-since-epoch
    # note the extra period gives us the extra right-hand bin boundary we need
    bounds = np.array(periods.to_timestamp(how='start'), dtype='int')
    # bin our time field as integers
    cut = pd.cut(np.array(dts, dtype='int'), bins=bounds, right=right)
    # relabel the bins using the periods, omitting the extra one at the end
    cut.levels = periods[:-1].format()
    return cut
```

Then we can do what I wanted:

```
df.groupby([dcut(df.recd, freq='m', right=False),dcut(df.ship, freq='m', right=False)]).count()
```

To get:

```
                price qty recd ship
2012-07 2012-10   1    1    1    1
2012-11 2012-12   1    1    1    1
        2013-03   1    1    1    1  
2012-12 2012-09   1    1    1    1
        2013-02   1    1    1    1  
2013-01 2012-08   1    1    1    1
2013-02 2013-02   1    1    1    1
2013-03 2013-03   1    1    1    1
2013-04 2012-07   1    1    1    1
        2013-03   1    1    1    1
```

I guess you could similarly define dqcut() which first "rounds" each datetime value to the integer representing the start of its containing period (at your specified frequency), and then uses qcut() to choose amongst those boundaries.  Or do qcut() first on the raw integer values and round the resulting bins based on your chosen frequency?

No joy on the bonus question yet? :)

Answer (score 0):

How about using `Series` and putting the parts of the `DataFrame` that you're interested into that, then calling `cut` on the series object?

```
price_series = pd.Series(df.price.tolist(), index=df.recd)
```

and then

```
 pd.qcut(price_series, q=3)
```

and so on. (Though I think @Jeff's answer is best)