# What is the difference between pandas.qcut and pandas.cut?

Tags: python, pandas

The documentation says:

http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/basics.html

"Continuous values can be discretized using the cut (bins based on values) and qcut (bins based on sample quantiles) functions"

Sounds very abstract to me... I can see the differences in the example below but **what does qcut (sample quantile) actually do/mean? When would you use qcut versus cut?**

Thanks.

```
factors = np.random.randn(30)

In [11]:
pd.cut(factors, 5)
Out[11]:
[(-0.411, 0.575], (-0.411, 0.575], (-0.411, 0.575], (-0.411, 0.575], (0.575, 1.561], ..., (-0.411, 0.575], (-1.397, -0.411], (0.575, 1.561], (-2.388, -1.397], (-0.411, 0.575]]
Length: 30
Categories (5, object): [(-2.388, -1.397] < (-1.397, -0.411] < (-0.411, 0.575] < (0.575, 1.561] < (1.561, 2.547]]

In [14]:
pd.qcut(factors, 5)
Out[14]:
[(-0.348, 0.0899], (-0.348, 0.0899], (0.0899, 1.19], (0.0899, 1.19], (0.0899, 1.19], ..., (0.0899, 1.19], (-1.137, -0.348], (1.19, 2.547], [-2.383, -1.137], (-0.348, 0.0899]]
Length: 30
Categories (5, object): [[-2.383, -1.137] < (-1.137, -0.348] < (-0.348, 0.0899] < (0.0899, 1.19] < (1.19, 2.547]]`
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16319106/whats-the-equivalent-of-cut-qcut-for-pandas-date-fields

Answer (score 279, accepted):

To begin, note that quantiles is just the most general term for things like percentiles, quartiles, and medians.  You specified five bins in your example, so you are asking `qcut` for quintiles.

So, when you ask for quintiles with `qcut`, the bins will be chosen so that you have the same number of records in each bin.  You have 30 records, so should have 6 in each bin (your output should look like this, although the breakpoints will differ due to the random draw):

```
pd.qcut(factors, 5).value_counts()

[-2.578, -0.829]    6
(-0.829, -0.36]     6
(-0.36, 0.366]      6
(0.366, 0.868]      6
(0.868, 2.617]      6
```

Conversely, for `cut` you will see something more uneven:

```
pd.cut(factors, 5).value_counts()

(-2.583, -1.539]    5
(-1.539, -0.5]      5
(-0.5, 0.539]       9
(0.539, 1.578]      9
(1.578, 2.617]      2
```

That's because `cut` will choose the bins to be evenly spaced according to the values themselves and not the *frequency* of those values.  Hence, because you drew from a random normal, you'll see higher frequencies in the inner bins and fewer in the outer.  This is essentially going to be a tabular form of a histogram (which you would expect to be fairly bell shaped with 30 records).

Comment: Great answer for *what* it is. Could you speak to *why* you would choose one over the other?

Comment: @JamesHulse that's a fair question but I don't have a general answer.  it just depends on whether you are looking for an absolute measure vs a relative (quantile) measure more than anything else.  Consider height, for example:  you might be interested in relative height (over 6 ft tall) and use `cut` or you might care more about the tallest 5% and use `qcut`

Comment: basically pd.qcut must be used to get an 'equidepth' discretization, while pd.cut should be used to get an 'equiwidth' discretization

Answer (score 49):

- cut command creates **equispaced bins** but frequency of samples
  is **unequal in each bin**
- qcut command creates **unequal size bins** but frequency of samples is **equal
  in each bin.**

[image]

```
    >>> x=np.array([24,  7,  2, 25, 22, 29])
    >>> x
    array([24,  7,  2, 25, 22, 29])

    >>> pd.cut(x,3).value_counts() #Bins size has equal interval of 9
    (2, 11.0]        2
    (11.0, 20.0]     0
    (20.0, 29.0]     4

    >>> pd.qcut(x,3).value_counts() #Equal frequecy of 2 in each bins
    (1.999, 17.0]     2
    (17.0, 24.333]    2
    (24.333, 29.0]    2
```

Comment: x, bins=pd.cut(list_of_values,bins=10,labels=list(range(10,0,-1)), retbins = True)  
This is helpful to get bins

Answer (score 12):

So qcut ensures a more even distribution of the values in each bin even if they cluster in the sample space. This means you are less likely to have a bin full of data with very close values and another bin with 0 values. In general, it's better sampling.

Answer (score -1):

Pd.qcut distribute elements of an array on making division on the basis of ((no.of elements in array)/(no. of bins - 1)), then divide this much no. of elements serially in each bins.

Pd.cut distribute elements of an array on making division on the basis of ((first +last element)/(no. of bins-1)) and then distribute element according to the range of values in which they fall.