# Numpy "where" with multiple conditions

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I try to add a new column "energy_class" to a dataframe "df_energy" which it contains the string "high" if the "consumption_energy" value > 400, "medium" if the "consumption_energy" value is between 200 and 400, and "low" if the "consumption_energy" value is under 200.
I try to use  np.where from numpy, but I see that `numpy.where(condition[, x, y])` treat only two condition not 3 like in my case.

Any idea to help me please?

Thank you in advance

Comment: Why just don't use `numpy.select()`?

Answer (score 93, accepted):

You can use a [ternary](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394809/does-python-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator):

```
np.where(consumption_energy > 400, 'high', 
         (np.where(consumption_energy < 200, 'low', 'medium')))
```

Comment: I think this is great, except if you have complex multiple condition, then this can be a big issue.

Comment: Agreed. For anything more complex, I would use the `pd.cut` solution by @Maxu.

Answer (score 137):

Try this:
Using the setup from @Maxu

```
col         = 'consumption_energy'
conditions  = [ df2[col] >= 400, (df2[col] < 400) & (df2[col]> 200), df2[col] <= 200 ]
choices     = [ "high", 'medium', 'low' ]
    
df2["energy_class"] = np.select(conditions, choices, default=np.nan)


  consumption_energy energy_class
0                 459         high
1                 416         high
2                 186          low
3                 250       medium
4                 411         high
5                 210       medium
6                 343       medium
7                 328       medium
8                 208       medium
9                 223       medium
```

Comment: This is fantastic.  As a note, this works like most `if / elif / else` functions in that if the first _and_ the second conditions are met, the first will apply and not the second.  Thanks @Merlin

Comment: I am trying to use this setup but in my condition I am checking if the column contains certain string values and this is not working and I am getting the error (ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous.). Any ideas why? Here is my question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64806956/manipulating-dataset-feature-using-string-comparison-in-python

Comment: This is good solution. Using `np.where` can make code hard to read sometime. For only `if-else`, `np.where` is good.

Comment: I am using Python 3.7.3 and cannot use AND, OR logic in this way within conditions. No error is given but the result is wrong. Rather had to use then separately as shown in the documentation [link](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) and the expected result is given pretty fast.

Answer (score 28):

I like to keep the code clean. That's why I prefer `np.vectorize` for such tasks.

```
def conditions(x):
    if   x > 400:   return "High"
    elif x > 200:   return "Medium"
    else:           return "Low"

func         = np.vectorize(conditions)
energy_class = func(df_energy["consumption_energy"])
```

Then just add numpy array as a column in your dataframe using:

```
df_energy["energy_class"] = energy_class
```

The advantage in this approach is that if you wish to add more complicated constraints to a column, it can be done easily.
Hope it helps.

Answer (score 22):

I would use the [cut()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.cut.html) method here, which will generate very efficient and memory-saving `category` dtype:

```
In [124]: df
Out[124]:
   consumption_energy
0                 459
1                 416
2                 186
3                 250
4                 411
5                 210
6                 343
7                 328
8                 208
9                 223

In [125]: pd.cut(df.consumption_energy,
                 [0, 200, 400, np.inf],
                 labels=['low','medium','high']
          )
Out[125]:
0      high
1      high
2       low
3    medium
4      high
5    medium
6    medium
7    medium
8    medium
9    medium
Name: consumption_energy, dtype: category
Categories (3, object): [low < medium < high]
```

Comment: Hey max, in this method is 200 included in medium or low?

Comment: @Datanovice, it should fall under “medium “ category because all right edges of intervals are included per default

Comment: @Datanovice, actually I’m wrong  - it should fall under the “low” category as it is a right edge of the first interval

Answer (score 6):

Let's start by creating a dataframe with `1000000` random numbers between `0` and `1000` to be used as test

```
df_energy = pd.DataFrame({'consumption_energy': np.random.randint(0, 1000, 1000000)})

[Out]:

   consumption_energy
0                 683
1                 893
2                 545
3                  13
4                 768
5                 385
6                 644
7                 551
8                 572
9                 822
```

A bit of a description of the dataframe

```
print(df.energy.describe())

[Out]:
       consumption_energy
count      1000000.000000
mean           499.648532
std            288.600140
min              0.000000
25%            250.000000
50%            499.000000
75%            750.000000
max            999.000000
```

There are various ways to achieve that, such as:

1. Using [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

   ```
   df_energy['energy_class'] = np.where(df_energy['consumption_energy'] > 400, 'high', np.where(df_energy['consumption_energy'] > 200, 'medium', 'low'))
   ```
2. Using [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html)

   ```
   df_energy['energy_class'] = np.select([df_energy['consumption_energy'] > 400, df_energy['consumption_energy'] > 200], ['high', 'medium'], default='low')
   ```
3. Using [`numpy.vectorize`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html)

   ```
   df_energy['energy_class'] = np.vectorize(lambda x: 'high' if x > 400 else ('medium' if x > 200 else 'low'))(df_energy['consumption_energy'])
   ```
4. Using [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

   ```
   df_energy['energy_class'] = pd.cut(df_energy['consumption_energy'], bins=[0, 200, 400, 1000], labels=['low', 'medium', 'high'])
   ```
5. Using Python's built in modules

   ```
   def energy_class(x):
     if x > 400:
         return 'high'
     elif x > 200:
         return 'medium'
     else:
         return 'low'

   df_energy['energy_class'] = df_energy['consumption_energy'].apply(energy_class)
   ```
6. Using a lambda function

   ```
   df_energy['energy_class'] = df_energy['consumption_energy'].apply(lambda x: 'high' if x > 400 else ('medium' if x > 200 else 'low'))
   ```

---

**Time Comparison**

From all the tests that I've done, by measuring time with `time.perf_counter()` ([for other ways to measure time of execution see this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1557571/7109869)), [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html) was the fastest approach.

```
                        method      time
0                   np.where()  0.124139
1                  np.select()  0.155879
2            numpy.vectorize()  0.452789
3                 pandas.cut()  0.046143
4  Python's built-in functions  0.138021
5              lambda function   0.19081
```

[image]

---

**Notes:**

- For the difference between `pandas.cut` and `pandas.qcut` see this: [What is the difference between pandas.qcut and pandas.cut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211923/what-is-the-difference-between-pandas-qcut-and-pandas-cut)

Comment: Interesting...  Would be nice to turn the analysis into a matrix.  The data above is for 1 million records.  How would it look for 10k, 100k, 1m, 10m?  Also, what if different data types are used, e.g. string, integers, etc.

Answer (score 4):

## WARNING: Be careful with NaNs

Always be careful that if your data has missing values `np.where` may be tricky to use and may give you the wrong result inadvertently.

Consider this situation:

```
df['cons_ener_cat'] = np.where(df.consumption_energy > 400, 'high', 
         (np.where(df.consumption_energy < 200, 'low', 'medium')))

# if we do not use this second line, then
#  if consumption energy is missing it would be shown medium, which is WRONG.
df.loc[df.consumption_energy.isnull(), 'cons_ener_cat'] = np.nan
```

Alternatively, you can use one-more nested `np.where` for medium versus nan which would be ugly.

IMHO best way to go is `pd.cut`.  It deals with NaNs and easy to use.

## Examples:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns

df = sns.load_dataset('titanic')

# pd.cut
df['age_cat'] = pd.cut(df.age, [0, 20, 60, np.inf], labels=['child','medium','old'])


# manually add another line for nans
df['age_cat2'] = np.where(df.age > 60, 'old', (np.where(df.age <20, 'child', 'medium')))
df.loc[df.age.isnull(), 'age_cat'] = np.nan

# multiple nested where
df['age_cat3'] = np.where(df.age > 60, 'old',
                         (np.where(df.age <20, 'child',
                                   np.where(df.age.isnull(), np.nan, 'medium'))))

# outptus
print(df[['age','age_cat','age_cat2','age_cat3']].head(7))
    age age_cat age_cat2 age_cat3
0  22.0  medium   medium   medium
1  38.0  medium   medium   medium
2  26.0  medium   medium   medium
3  35.0  medium   medium   medium
4  35.0  medium   medium   medium
5   NaN     NaN   medium      nan
6  54.0  medium   medium   medium
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this : Even if `consumption_energy` contains nulls don't worry about it.

```
def egy_class(x):
    '''
    This function assigns classes as per the energy consumed.
    ''' 
    return ('high' if x>400 else
             'low' if x<200 else 'medium')
chk = df_energy.consumption_energy.notnull()
df_energy['energy_class'] = df_energy.consumption_energy[chk].apply(egy_class)
```

Answer (score 0):

I second using np.vectorize.  It is much faster than np.where and also cleaner code wise.  You can definitely tell the speed up with larger data sets.  You can use a dictionary format for your conditionals as well as the output of those conditions.

```
# Vectorizing with numpy 
row_dic = {'Condition1':'high',
          'Condition2':'medium',
          'Condition3':'low',
          'Condition4':'lowest'}

def Conditions(dfSeries_element,dictionary):
    '''
    dfSeries_element is an element from df_series 
    dictionary: is the dictionary of your conditions with their outcome
    '''
    if dfSeries_element in dictionary.keys():
        return dictionary[dfSeries]

def VectorizeConditions():
    func = np.vectorize(Conditions)
    result_vector = func(df['Series'],row_dic)
    df['new_Series'] = result_vector

    # running the below function will apply multi conditional formatting to your df
VectorizeConditions()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
myassign["assign3"]=np.where(myassign["points"]>90,"genius",(np.where((myassign["points"]>50) & (myassign["points"]<90),"good","bad"))
```

when you wanna use only "where" method but with multiple condition. we can add more condition by adding more (np.where) by the same method like we did above. and again the last two will be one you want.