# Switch boolean output to string in pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

When comparing two dataframes and putting the result back into a dataframe:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'Column':[1,2,3,4]})
```

or in human readable form:

```
    Column
0   1
1   2
2   3
3   4

dfB = pd.DataFrame({'Column':[1,2,4,3]})
```

or in human readable form:

```
    Column
0   1
1   2
2   4
3   3

pd.DataFrame(dfA > dfB)
```

pandas outputs a dataframe with true or false values.

```
    Column
0   False
1   False
2   False
3   True
```

Is it possible to change the name from 'true' or 'false' to 'lower' or 'higher'?
I want to know if the outcome is higher, lower or equal, that is why I ask.
If the output is not higher or lower, (true or false) then it must be equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend `np.where` for performance/simplicity.

```
pd.DataFrame(np.where(dfA > dfB, 'higher', 'lower'), columns=['col'])

      col
0   lower
1   lower
2   lower
3  higher
```

---

You can also nest conditions if needed with `np.where`,

```
m1 = dfA > dfB
m2 = dfA < dfB  
pd.DataFrame(
    np.where(m1, 'higher', np.where(m2, 'lower', 'equal')),
    columns=['col']
)
```

Or, follow a slightly different approach with `np.select`.

```
pd.DataFrame(
    np.select([m1, m2], ['higher', 'lower'], default='equal'),
    columns=['col']
)
```

```
      col
0   equal
1   equal
2   lower
3  higher
```

Comment: I used a ternary  as suggested here: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions/39109969]

Comment: @nappingkid cut is an interesting solution. The ternery you mention is much like what is in my answer here.

Answer (score 2):

You may use [`map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html):

```
In [10]: pd.DataFrame(dfA > dfB)['Column'].map({True: 'higher', False: 'lower'})
Out[10]:
0     lower
1     lower
2     lower
3    higher
Name: Column, dtype: object
```

Comment: This is an interesting approach, would this method be able to work with several columns at the same time. Like when comparing dataframes with multiple columns?
+ How would I include is neither higher or lower, but equal to this method?

Comment: I add to your solution according to [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions/39109969]. So, you gave the right answer for my case. But you need to add the ternary solution here.