# pandas: multiple row conditions based on different row values

Tags: pandas

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

colors = np.array(['blue','white', 'black', 'blue','white', 'black'])
money = np.array(['666', '777', '888','100', '300', '200'])

df = pd.DataFrame({'AAA': colors, 'BBB': money})
print(df)
```

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B4yik.png)

hello,

what i want basically: where the row equals black, multiply the values on column BBB by 5, where the row equals white, multiply the values on column BBB by 10, and where the row equals blue, divide the values on column BBB by 7

thank you

Comment: What is your attempt to solve it? Please don't expect free answers here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy "where" with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
df['BBB']= df['BBB'].astype('int')
df.loc[df.AAA=='black', 'BBB'] = df['BBB']*5
df.loc[df.AAA=='white', 'BBB'] = df['BBB']*10
df.loc[df.AAA=='blue', 'BBB'] = df['BBB']/7
```