# Create a new Conditional Dataframe Series from multiple Dataframes

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to create a new data frame from multiple data frames in one statement.

For Eg:

```
df.loc[(df[[A,B]].mean(axis=1) <= Const1), 'D'] = df['F']

df.loc[(df[[A,B]].mean(axis=1) >  Const1) & (df['E']<=Const2), 'D'] = df['G']

df.loc[(df[[A,B]].mean(axis=1) >  Const1) & (df['E']> Const2), 'D'] = df['H']
```

TO

```
df['D'] = 'some statement'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy "where" with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions)

Comment: In particular the answer of [Merlin](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39111919/9274732) from the link above

Comment: This wont work ere because 'High" , " Medium" & 'low' are constants in the provided solution. What I need is the value corresponding to some indices from another dataframe with non-constant values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [`np.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html) as in the link provided, even if what you want the choices to be series and not constant, it works the same way.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# example data
np.random.seed(0)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,100, 30).reshape(-1, 6), 
                  columns=list('ABEFGH'))
Const1, Const2 = 50, 50

# conditions
conds = [(df[['A','B']].mean(axis=1) <= Const1), 
         (df[['A','B']].mean(axis=1) >  Const1) & (df['E']<=Const2), 
         (df[['A','B']].mean(axis=1) >  Const1) & (df['E']> Const2)]
# choices that are series
choices = [df['F'], df['G'], df['H']]

#use np.select
df['D'] = np.select(condlist=conds, choicelist=choices)
print(df)
    A   B   E   F   G   H   D
0  44  47  64  67  67   9  67 #value from F
1  83  21  36  87  70  88  70 #value from G
2  88  12  58  65  39  87  65
3  46  88  81  37  25  77  77 #value from H
4  72   9  20  80  69  79  80
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, very useful and very well explained.