# Using multiple conditions in a column to prepare it for analysis

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I used following condition to prepare a dataframe for analysis.

```
def DAYS(DF_FRAME_NAME):
    if (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column1'] == 'Yes' and (DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS'] == 1)):
        return 3
    elif (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column1'] == 'Yes' and (DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS'] == 2)):
        return 3
    if (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column2'] == 'YES' and (DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS'] == 1)):
        return 3
    elif (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column2'] == 'YES' and (DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS'] == 2)):
        return 3
    elif (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column2'] == 'YES' and (DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS'] == 3)):
        return 5
    elif (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column2'] == 'YES' and (DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS'] == 4)):
        return 5
    elif (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column2'] == 'YES' and (DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS'] == 5)):
        return 5
    elif (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column1'] != 'Yes'):
        return DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS']
    elif (DF_FRAME_NAME['Column2']) != 'YES':
        return DF_FRAME_NAME['DAYS']
df['DAYS'] = df.apply(DAYS, axis =1)
```

Above function consume time therefore with the help of @deadshot I re-write the code as follows:

```
DF['DAYS']=np.where((DF['column1'].eq('Yes')) &(DF['DAYS'].eq(1)),3,DF[‘DAYS’])
    DF[‘DAYS’]=np.where((DF[‘column1’].eq('Yes')) & (DF[‘DAYS’].eq(2)),3,DF[‘DAYS’])
    DF[‘DAYS’]=np.where((DF[‘column2’].eq('YES')) & (DF[‘DAYS’].eq(1)),3,DF[‘DAYS’])
    DF[‘DAYS’]=np.where((DF[‘column2’].eq('YES')) & (DF[‘DAYS’].eq(2),3,DF[‘DAYS’])
    DF[‘DAYS’]=np.where((DF[‘column2’].eq('YES')) & (DF[‘DAYS’].eq(3)),5,DF[‘DAYS’])
    DF[‘DAYS’]=np.where((DF[‘column2’].eq('YES')) & (DF[‘DAYS’].eq(5)),5,DF[‘DAYS’])
    DF[‘DAYS’]=np.where((DF[‘column2’].eq('YES')) & (DF[‘DAYS’].eq(5)),5,DF[‘DAYS’])
    DF[‘DAYS’]=np.where(DF[‘column1’].eq('No'),DF[‘DAYS’],1)
    DF[‘DAYS’]=np.where(DF[‘column2’].eq('No'),DF[‘DAYS’],1)
```

Peformance-wise above code is much faster when applying to dataframe over 200,000 rows.
But is it correct method? Can I use a custom function inside a where function? Please help how to write the above codes more appealing because there are many conditions applicable to same column.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions/39111919#39111919

Comment: try: (DF[‘column1’].eq('Yes')) & (DF[‘DAYS’].isin([1,2])

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html

Comment: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html