# How to add new colum into existing df with values based on existing columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Have marked the current Df and the expected output.
I would like to add a new column "Rank" based on the values of "Score" with the conditions as `IF SCORE>=80,"EXP", ELSE IF SCORE<=34,"FAIL",ELSE,"PASS"`

Request guidance.

Current and expected results:

[image: xxx]

Comment: please, don't post images of code, input, output, errors. Copy/paste here as text. see [ask].

Comment: I suggest you improve your question, add some examples, some code and make it more clear what you want to achieve. Have a look here => [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: check out this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions

Answer (score 1):

Create the DataFrame:

```py
df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['a','b','c','d','e','f'],
                   'Score':[65,75,85,35,20,34]})
```

Then add a new column `RANK` with the condition you asked:

```py
df['Rank'] = ['EXP' if i>=85 else 'FAIL' if i<=34  else 'PASS' for i in df['Score']]
```

Result:

```py
print(df)

  Name  Score  Rank
0    a     65  PASS
1    b     75  PASS
2    c     85   EXP
3    d     35  PASS
4    e     20  FAIL
5    f     34  FAIL
```