# Changing rows within MultiIndex, DataFrame within a for loop

Tags: python, pandas

I am currently trying to iterate through a dataframe containing MultIndex and calculate a signal that will make the SIGNAL column either 1.0, -1.0 or stay at 0.

Below is an example of how the DataFrame looks.
|   |      |         |          AAPL|  |       |              | AMZN|
|:-|:-------:| :--------:| :----------: |:-:|:-------:| :-----------:|---------: |
| SIGNAL| close  | BB_LOWER  | BB_UPPER  |  SIGNAL | close   | BB_LOWER     | BB_UPPER  |
| |        |           |              |  |       |              |           |
|0 |  123   | 123       | 123          | 0|123     |  123         | 123       |
| 0|  123   | 123       | 123          | 0|123     |  123         | 123       |

This is the code I have been trying to tinker with and create so the output is accurate.

```
for x in ticker_list:
    for index, row in df[x].iterrows():
        if row['close'] < row['BB_LOWER']:
            df[x, 'SIGNAL'].loc[index] = 1.0
        if row['close'] > row['BB_UPPER']:
            df[x, 'SIGNAL'].loc[index] = -1.0
 df.sort_index(axis=1)
```

I understand the problem is coming from these sections but I have been unable to come to a solution.

```
df[x, 'SIGNAL'].loc[index] = 1.0
```

and

```
df[x, 'SIGNAL'].loc[index] = -1.0
```

My output is, every row in the SIGNAL column is changing to -1.0

|  |  |  | AAPL |  |  |  | AMZN |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| SIGNAL | close | BB_LOWER | BB_UPPER | SIGNAL | close | BB_LOWER | BB_UPPER |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |
| -1 | 123 | 123 | 123 | -1 | 123 | 123 | 123 |
| -1 | 123 | 123 | 123 | -1 | 123 | 123 | 123 |

Ideally I would like to keep this DataFrame in MultiIndex form.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: For some reason my first table is not formatting correctly. It is basically the same as the second table except the SIGNAL columns contain only 0's

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Numpy "where" with multiple conditions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39109045/numpy-where-with-multiple-conditions)