# Split pandas series into buckets with qcut

Tags: python, pandas

I'm trying to split a series into buckets of *almost* the same size keeping the order and without having same items in different buckets.
I'm using qcut like this:

```
>>> import pandas as pd 
>>> pd.__version__
'0.20.3'
>>> x = [1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,3,4]
>>> pd.qcut(x, 10, duplicates='drop').value_counts()
(0.999, 2.0]    9
(2.0, 3.0]      1
(3.0, 4.0]      1
dtype: int64
```

I was expecting this to split the first bucket into `(0.999, 1.0]`, `(1.0, 2.0]`.
Why not? Any other approach I should try?

Answer (score 0):

By using `cut` specific your own interval

```
pd.cut(x, [0.999,1,2]).value_counts()
Out[242]: 
(0.999, 1.0]    5
(1.0, 2.0]      4
dtype: int64
```

Comment: But I don't know the intervals (the `x` from the question is a simple example, the real `x` is much bigger)

Comment: @pomber you can check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211923/what-is-the-difference-between-pandas-qcut-and-pandas-cut

Answer (score 0):

Try pd.cut option like below :

```
pd.cut(x, 3).value_counts()

(0.997, 2.0]    9
(2.0, 3.0]      1
(3.0, 4.0]      1
```

Play around with the number of bins you provide.Here I have provided 3 bins. So it had splitted into (0.997,2), (2,3), (3,4).

If you want the bin value to be specified by you then mention the bin values manually like below :

```
bins = [0.999, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0]
pd.cut(x, bins).value_counts()

(0.999, 1.0]    5
(1.0, 2.0]      4
(2.0, 3.0]      1
(3.0, 4.0]      1
```

Hope this helps.