# How do I cut a column in two bins and aggregate data per bin using groupby?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

So, this is my dataframe.

```
session_id  question_difficulty     attempt_updated_at
5c822af21c1fba22            2   1557470128000
5c822af21c1fba22            3   1557469685000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557470079000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557472999000
5c822af21c1fba22            3   1557474145000
5c822af21c1fba22            3   1557474441000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557474299000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557474738000
5c822af21c1fba22            3   1557475430000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557476960000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557477458000
5c822af21c1fba22            2   1557478118000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557482556000
5c822af21c1fba22            4   1557482809000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557482886000
5c822af21c1fba22            5   1557484232000
```

I want to cut the field 'attempt_updated_at'(**which is epoch time**) into 2 equal bins and find mean of 'question_difficulty' in that bin per session.

I want to store the mean of 1st bin and 2nd bin separately.

I tried to go through pd.cut but I do not know how to use it.

I expect my output to be like,

for example,

```
session_id         mean1_difficulty       mean2_difficulty
5c822af21c1fba22            5.0                3.0
```

Any idea is appreciated,
Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you need [`qcut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html) with aggregate `mean`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['session_id', pd.qcut(df['attempt_updated_at'], 2, labels=False)])
         ['question_difficulty'].mean()
                                .unstack()
                                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'mean{x+1}_difficulty'))
print (df1)
attempt_updated_at  mean1_difficulty  mean2_difficulty
session_id                                            
5c822af21c1fba22                 3.5             4.125
```

Or [`cut`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.cut.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby(['session_id', pd.cut(df['attempt_updated_at'], 2, labels=False)])
         ['question_difficulty'].mean()
                                .unstack()
                                .rename(columns=lambda x: f'mean{x+1}_difficulty'))
print (df1)
attempt_updated_at  mean1_difficulty  mean2_difficulty
session_id                                            
5c822af21c1fba22            3.444444          4.285714
```

Difference between functions is better explain [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30211923).

Comment: Thank you it works, but is there a way in the pd.cut method to filter out rows which will have 0 in either 'mean1_difficulty' or 'mean2_difficulty' ?

Comment: @RedDragon - Do you think filter by [boolean indexing](https://stackoverflow.com/q/17071871) ?

Comment: @RedDragon - use `df = df[pd.cut(df['attempt_updated_at'], 2, labels=False) == 0]`

Answer (score 1):

I think that should do it:

```
pdf.sort_values('attempt_updated_at', ascending=False, inplace=True).reset_index(drop=True)
first = pdf.iloc[:pdf.shape[0] // 2]
second = pdf.iloc[pdf.shape[0] // 2:]

res = pd.DataFrame(first.groupby('session_id')['question_difficulty'].agg('mean')) \
    .rename(columns={'question_difficulty': 'mean1_difficulty'}) \
    .join(second.groupby('session_id')['question_difficulty'].agg('mean')) \
    .rename(columns={'question_difficulty': 'mean2_difficulty'})
```

Comment: **first = pdf.iloc[:pdf.shape[0] // 2]
second = pdf.iloc[pdf.shape[0] // 2:]**

This will divide the dataframe but i want to divide it based on the epoch time.

Comment: I misunderstood, only followed the need to cut it "into 2 equal bins".... anyhows, sorting the data-frame by the epoch column would still be a winner.

Comment: There, I have edited the code to support the cutting of data by the epoch time value (the "ascending=True" was just to make sure the index is indeed reset correctly, you can drop it.