# Converting numeric feature into categorical feature

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, numpy, histogram

I'm working on a problem to forecast future electronic store sales from historical data.  One of the features I'm using is *item price* (float).  I've found experimentally that adding this to an existing list of features degrades fitting and validation accuracy (increases prediction RMSE) of my `xgboost` model.  I suspect that the impact of price may be highly non-linear, with peaks at the prices of memory sticks, laptops, cell phones, etc.

Anyway, I got the following idea to cope with this:  How about if I convert the float *item price* to a categorical variable, with ability to specify the mapping, e.g., ranges of values or deciles?  Then, I could *mean-encode* that categorical variable using the training target value *item price*.

Does this make sense?  Could you give me a pointer to a Python "linear/decile histogrammer" that returns, for a list of float quantity, return a parallel list of which bin/decile each float belongs to?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMHO, you can use [`qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html), [`KBinsDiscretizer`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.KBinsDiscretizer.html) or [`cut`](http://%20https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.cut.html).

Some examples,

```py
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), columns=['a'])
>>> df
          a
0  0.060278
1 -0.618677
2 -0.472467
3  1.539958
4 -0.181974
5  1.563588
6 -1.693140
7  1.868881
8  1.072179
9  0.575978
```

For `qcut`,

```
>>> df['cluster'] = pd.qcut(df.a, 5, labels=range(1, 6))
>>> df
          a cluster
0  0.060278       3
1 -0.618677       1
2 -0.472467       2
3  1.539958       4
4 -0.181974       2
5  1.563588       5
6 -1.693140       1
7  1.868881       5
8  1.072179       4
9  0.575978       3
```

For `KBinsDiscretizer`,

```py
>>> (df['cluster'] = 
     KBinsDiscretizer(n_bins=3, encode='ordinal', strategy='quantile')
     .fit_transform(df.a.values.reshape(-1, 1)))
>>> df
          a  cluster
0  0.060278      1.0
1 -0.618677      0.0
2 -0.472467      0.0
3  1.539958      2.0
4 -0.181974      1.0
5  1.563588      2.0
6 -1.693140      0.0
7  1.868881      2.0
8  1.072179      2.0
9  0.575978      1.0
```

For `cut`,

```py
>>> df['cluster'] = pd.cut(df.a, 5, labels=range(1, 6))
>>> df
          a cluster
0  0.060278       3
1 -0.618677       2
2 -0.472467       2
3  1.539958       5
4 -0.181974       3
5  1.563588       5
6 -1.693140       1
7  1.868881       5
8  1.072179       4
9  0.575978       4
```

Finally, it may be useful to look at: [What is the difference between pandas.qcut and pandas.cut?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30211923/what-is-the-difference-between-pandas-qcut-and-pandas-cut)