# How do I assign groups to python-pandas data based on integer column?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with sales by month and the price at each month's observation.  Is there a way to take those prices, and break them up into 10 equal groups based on the price itself, so group 1 would be 10% with the lowest prices, and group 10 be 10% of the observations with the highest prices?

I tried `pd.cut` but I need to know where those 10% cut points are to bin correctly and I'm not sure how to get that when I have over 30K rows of data.  I also need equal number of observations in each group.

Here is some test data:

```
from scipy.stats import poisson
import pandas as pd

data = poisson.rvs(mu=42.73, size=10000)
data_ = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['price'])
```

Thank you.

Comment: [`pd.qcut(data_['price'], 10)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html).

Comment: My apologies as I forgot to add I needed the same amount of observations in each group.  Then add a column denoting the price group each observation is in.

Comment: `data_.groupby(pd.qcut(data_['price'], 10)).value_counts()`?

Comment: with only a relatively small number of discrete values (in comparison to the total number of observations) it'll be impossible to get equally sized groups

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let's create a dataframe to use as an example for OP's use case

```
import pandas as pd

sales = pd.DataFrame({'sales': [100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 600],
                        'price': [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6.0]})
```

Depending on one's goals one can use:

• [`pandas.cut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.cut.html)

```
sales['group'] = pd.cut(sales['price'], 10, labels=False)

[Out]:
   sales  price  group
0    100    1.0      0
1    200    2.0      1
2    300    3.0      3
3    400    4.0      5
4    500    5.0      7
```

• [`pandas.qcut`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.qcut.html)

```
sales['group'] = pd.qcut(sales['price'], 10, labels=False)

[Out]:
   sales  price  group
0    100    1.0      0
1    200    2.0      1
2    300    3.0      3
3    400    4.0      5
4    500    5.0      7
```

In this example the output is the same, but that is not necessarily the case. Therefore, for more information on the difference between `pandas.cut` and `pandas.qcut`, see this thread: [What is the difference between pandas.qcut and pandas.cut?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/30211923/7109869)

Additionally, if one wants to see the labels for the resulting bins, change `labels=False` to `labels=True`.

Finally, in order to get the amount of observations in each group, one can use [`pandas.DataFrame.groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html). Let's create a new dataframe called `group_counts`

```
group_counts = sales.groupby('group').size().reset_index(name='counts')

[Out]:
   group  counts
0      0       1
1      1       1
2      3       1
3      5       1
4      7       1
```

Comment: Thank you. This is good, but how do I ensure I get equal counts of observations into each group?  I have some outliers and they skew the cut.  I want 10 groups of equal (or near equal in the case of odd number observations) counts.

Comment: @Jordan for that instead `pd.cut` one needs to use `pd.qcut`.