# Pandas histogram of dates with empty bins

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

My use case is very simliar to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27365467/can-pandas-plot-a-histogram-of-dates/29036738#29036738), but my data is not continuous through each bin. I'm attempting to create multiple figures over the same time span to show activity (or lack thereof) over 18 months. I thought I hit the jackpot with the `df.groupby(df.date.month).count()` approach, but since my data is irregular I get different bins per dataset.

My question, then, is how would I go about creating some kind of master x-axis with fixed bins (month,year) and plot each dataset against these bins. I think I'm missing some fundamental understanding of either Pandas or MPL, and I apologize for what I'm sure is a silly question. First post, go easy...

Since I can't comment yet, I'll edit here:

I have 18 months generated with `pd.period_range`. I also have a DataFrame full of observations with timestamps within those months. Some of months have zero observations. How do I effectively count and chart the observations by month?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the suggestions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500894/pandas-pd-cut-binning-datetime-column-series)?

You can also try this sort of approach to manually define the bin boundaries

`bins = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120]
labels = [1, 2, 3, 4]
df['new_bin'] = pd.cut(df['existing_value'], bins=bins, labels=labels)`