# How can I speed up this nested loop using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, nested-loops

I am new to python and pandas. I am trying to assign new session IDs for around 2270 users, based on the time difference between the timestamps. If the time difference exceeds 4 hours, I want a new session ID. Otherwise, it would have to remain the same. In the end, I want a modified data frame with the new session ID column. Here is what I have so far:

```
Eh_2016["NewSessionID"] = 1 #Initialize 'NewSessionID' column in df with 1
Eh_2016['elapsed'] = datetime.time(0,0,0,0) #Create an empty elapsed to calculate Time diff later
users = Eh_2016['Username'].unique() #find the number of unique Usernames
for user in users: #start of the loop
    idx = Eh_2016.index[Eh_2016.Username == user] #Slice the original df
    temp = Eh_2016[Eh_2016.Username == user] #Create a temp placeholder for the slice
    counter = 1 # Initialize counter for NewSessionIDs
    for i,t in enumerate(temp['Timestamp']): #Looping for each timestamp value
        if i != 0 : 
            temp['elapsed'].iloc[i] = (t - temp['Timestamp'].iloc[i-1]) #Calculate diff btwn timestamps
            if temp['elapsed'].iloc[i] > datetime.timedelta(hours = 4): #If time diff>4
                counter +=1 #Increase counter value
                temp['NewSessionID'].iloc[i]=counter #Assign new counter value as NewSessionID
            else:
                temp['NewSessionID'].iloc[i] = counter #Retain previous sessionID
    Eh_2016.loc[idx,:]= temp #Replace original df with the updated slice
```

Any help on how to make this faster would be greatly appreciated! Let me know if you need more details. Thanks in advance.

Edit: Sample DF

```
        Username               Timestamp  NewSessionID                  Elapsed
126842  1095513 2016-06-30 20:58:30.477             1                 00:00:00
126843  1095513 2016-07-16 07:54:47.986             2  15 days 10:56:17.509000
126844  1095513 2016-07-16 07:54:47.986             2          0 days 00:00:00
126845  1095513 2016-07-16 07:55:10.986             2          0 days 00:00:23
126846  1095513 2016-07-16 07:55:13.456             2   0 days 00:00:02.470000
        ...                     ...           ...                      ...
146920  8641894 2016-08-11 22:26:14.051            31   0 days 04:50:23.415000
146921  8641894 2016-08-11 22:26:14.488            31   0 days 00:00:00.437000
146922  8641894 2016-08-12 20:01:02.419            32   0 days 21:34:47.931000
146923  8641894 2016-08-23 10:19:05.973            33  10 days 14:18:03.554000
146924  8641894 2016-09-25 11:30:35.540            34  33 days 01:11:29.567000
```

Comment: Welcome in SO. Please provide a [mcve](/help/mcve)

Comment: Please include a sample source DataFrame and the expected result.

Comment: Oh yea, no. Ruff. If you have a column with the date times you can use `pd.cut` to split it into months and assign them unique values that you can use to make random IDs. Check out this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500894/pandas-pd-cut-binning-datetime-column-series 

There is another way to do this but I can't remember rn.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the whole dataframe for each user is `O(users*sessions)`, and it's not needed since you need to iterate over the whole thing anyway.

A more efficient approach would be to instead iterate over the dataframe in one pass, and store the temporary variables (counter, location of previous row, etc) in a separate dataframe indexed by users.

```
Eh_2016["NewSessionID"] = 1 #Initialize 'NewSessionID' column in df with 1
Eh_2016['elapsed'] = datetime.time(0,0,0,0) #Create an empty elapsed to calculate Time diff later
# create new dataframe of unique users
users = pd.DataFrame({'Username': Eh_2016['Username'].unique()}).set_index('Username') 
# one column for the previous session looked at for each user
users['Previous'] = -1
# one column for the counter variable
users['Counter'] = 0

# iterate over each row
for index, row in Eh_2016.iterrows(): #start of the loop
    user = row['Username']
    previous = users[user, 'Previous']
    if previous >= 0: # if this is not the first row for this user
        Eh_2016.loc[index, 'elapsed'] = (row['Timestamp'] - Eh_2016.loc[previous, 'Timestamp']) #Calculate diff btwn timestamps
        if Eh_2016.loc[index, 'elapsed'] > datetime.timedelta(hours = 4): #If time diff>4
            users[user,'Counter'] += 1 #Increase counter value
        Eh_2016.loc[index, 'NewSessionID'] = users[user,'Counter'] # Assign new counter value as NewSessionID
        users[user, 'Previous'] = index # remember this row as the latest row for this user
```