# Sum of values while grouping in pandas

Tags: pandas, datetime, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas DataFrame that looks like this

```
Date         item   count
2019-01-01   i1     25
2019-01-01   i2     46
2019-01-02   i1     97
2019-01-02   i2     23
2019-01-02   i3     26
2019-01-03   i4     237
2019-01-04   i2     25
2019-01-10   i2     59
```

Date is of type datetime

I am looking for a way to get the sum of each of the items grouped into weekly bins. The resulting dataframe should look like this:

```
Week                       i1      i2     i3    i4
(2019-01-01, 2019-01-08]   122     94     26    237
(2019-01-08, 2019-01-15]   0       59     0     0
```

I have looked at [Pandas pd.cut() - binning datetime column / series](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500894/pandas-pd-cut-binning-datetime-column-series) to create date bins, but I don't want the count of items grouped by the bins, rather the sum of the count of items grouped by the bins. So far, the only working solution I have is to use `pandas.iterrows()` and iterate over each row. Is there a better way of doing this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have `unstack` after `groupby`

```
s=df.groupby([df.Date.dt.week,df.item])['count'].sum().unstack(fill_value=0)
Out[204]: 
item   i1  i2  i3   i4
Date                  
1     122  94  26  237
2       0  59   0    0
```

Comment: Thank you! This saved me a lot of time!